# Admob Ads Loaded but not shown in the andrioid app - Only test ads shown up

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I have integrated Admob Ads in my Android App.

Test Ads are visible.

When i run the application on other devices, in logcat it shows Log from OnAdLoaded.

But the Ad is not visible on the screen.

What could be the possible reason? And any solution you can suggest would be appreciated

**Java Code**

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-7480926640170381~7951418856");
        adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("EDDA7ADAB0640D8A735BAD5C5AD56F06")
                .addTestDevice("92C2E8C0BE19A733B5E747993F8DCB69")
                .build();


        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdLoaded");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdFailedToLoad");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
                // covers the screen.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdOpened");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdLeftApplication");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
                // to the app after tapping on an ad.
                Log.i("Ads", "onAdClosed");
            }
        });

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
XML CODE:
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7480926640170381/1386010508">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

Gradle
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0'
```

Comment: Its difficult to say without looking at the code, but a couple of things you can try out - 1. Are the other devices registered against emails for test devices? , 2. Are you actually getting ad content from AdMob?

Comment: here is my code

Comment: i just edited my question please check @NileshRajani

Answer (score 0):

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-5303090875900545",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>
```

Comment: where to add this script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a payment method with AdMob before your ads become visible.